# What Lego set has the most unique colours?

Tags: sets, history, colour

What Lego set, past or current has had the most unique colours (colors) regardless of piece count?

I've found [bricklink's color list](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp) but I have not found any way to filter sets biased on most colors.

Comment: Hi David and welcome to Bricks StackExchange. Quite an puzzling and interesting question, I would have no clue how to look for a definitive answer. Although large sets may seem good candidates at first, maybe basic bricks assortments would be a better guess; for example [10664](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10664-1) appears to have 20 different colors

Comment: An extra twist would be finding sets with most colours *visible on the outside*.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea where to find any sources for an answer, but I can offer a guess.

When it came out [70620 Ninjago City](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=156531#T=I) was the set with the most different elements ever made (That wasn't hard to verify, if I can remember how, I'll check later if it still is, and if any other contenders offer more colours), a guess is that they will come in many different colours. And they do, if I counted correctly there's 51 different colours in that set, quite a bit more than the 20 @Joubarc mentioned in a comment.