# By number of distinct colors, what official LEGO set has the most pieces?

Tags: set-identification, history

A [recent question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/13120/8229) shows the "monochrome" Steamboat Willie set actually contains about 20 colors. I was expecting fewer, maybe a dozen or so at most. So this got me wondering...

**By number of distinct brick colors, what official LEGO set has the most pieces?**

For example:

- 1 color: ____?
- 2 colors: Maybe 27 pieces for [40045 Shark](https://brickset.com/sets/40045-1/Shark)
- 3 colors: Maybe 1211 pieces for [21050 Architecture Studio](https://brickset.com/sets/21050-1/Architecture-Studio)
- 4 colors: ____?
- 5 colors: ____?
- ...
- 50 colors: ____?
- ....

Each transparent color counts as a distinct color, as does metallic and glitter, and historic colors count, too. As shared in a comment, Bricklink recognizes [up to about 100 colors](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp?utm_content=subnav). Colors on mini-figures do not count.

Past or current sets count. The only stipulation is that the set is an official LEGO one. This question might show a trend in themes: Architecture for example probably wins on fewest colors / most pieces, while Creator might take most colors / most pieces.

A similar question asks: [What Lego set has the most unique colours?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/12934/8229)

Comment: Your URL points to TLG color palette available in 2016. However, some colors have been discontinued and some new ones were introduced since then. Bricklink recognise more than [100](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp?utm_content=subnav)

Comment: @Alex Ooh, you are right. I had forgotten about the glitter and metallic and orher effects bricks, as well as historically the color palette changing. Thank you for bringing this up: I will amend my question.

Comment: A/some trivial data points to your list can be found by counting the number of colours in the set(s) containing the most pieces overall. No matter how many pieces are in the MF, that  set must take the price for that number of colors.

Answer (score 5):

I have a few:

- 3 colors: 2882 parts for [3450](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=3450-1)
- 6/5 colors: 4502 parts for
  [40179](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=40179-1). Note: color count depends if you include brick separator
  as a part or not.
- 11 colors: 2428 parts for [10181](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10181-1)
- 15 colors: 2455 parts for [2000431](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=2000431-1)
- 23 colors: 7513 for [75192](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75192-1)
- 37 colors: 2613 parts for [2000430](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=2000430-1)

Comment: Awesome list. That's an interesting point about the separator. I think the separator would count, as it is identifiably colored like a brick -- unlike minifigs whose colors aren't documented, I think.